# Html a tag "tel" attribute not working in android chrome

Tags: html

Html a tag "tel" attribute not working in android chrome.
I am trying to add click to call using  tag 
like 
+971XXXXXXXXX

This is working in all browsers in mobile except Chrome in some pages.I just want to know specific requirements for this to work in a HTML page.

Comment: You are using an input element with the type „tel“ or what exactly? Please post your code to make sure everybody understands your problem.